# Android ConstraintLayout set height based on screen size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Following is my xml layout. Trying to set height of ConstraintLayout based on screen width unable to do that it is not working. How to set height of ConstraintLayout based on screen size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:background="@color/accent_secondary"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/accent_secondary"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:0.35">



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:0.35"

Comment: Ah I see, to use constraint layout attributes, your views have to be inside a constraint layout. That's the point of a view group, to arrange it's children.